# How to echo crypt or md5 to plain text

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
 $username = md5($_POST($username));
 echo $username
 $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (username) VALUES ('$username')";
?>
<html>
      <form action = "index.php" method = "post">
        <input type = "text" name = "username">
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit">
      </form>
<html>
```

What i want is that after the form is submitted to the database which is already in md5 form, i want it to echo it to the page in plain text like: "Welcome john". John is from the database which is in md5 form.

Comment: i didn't see any form here? Also what you are doing ? code is total mess. lot of mistakes?

Comment: but what is it? `$_POST($username)`? maybe u need `md5($_POST['username']);`

Comment: i dont think `Welcome EC44E1B8B6240711CEB04741A3E0C2A1` would add much for the user experiance

Comment: Which `form` are you talking about?

Comment: Your question is not clear, update your question with proper info.

Comment: Start at the beginning https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_forms.htm **SO != a tutorial site**

Answer (score 3):

You have to do it in following manner:-

```
<html>
<form method = "POST"> <!-- form is required-->
      <input type = "text" name = "username">
      <input type = "password" name = "password">
      <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"> <!-- a submit button -->
</form>
<html>
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);//check all type of errors
ini_set('display_errors',1);// display those errors

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){ // check both values are coming or not?

    echo $username = $_POST['username']."<br/>";

    echo  $password = md5($_POST['password']);

}else{
  echo "Please fill the form!";
}
```

Note:-

I don't think anything useful you are going to get through this code (because it's just printing out values)

Also instead of `md5` use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: Here is the proper way of doing, what OP wanted but didn't explain properly.

Comment: @Drone  thanks. I hope it will help OP

Comment: @Anant Thanks! I will try this out!

Comment: ok, im a beginner in this site sorry if my posts are wrong.